# Video is lost after crashing

Tags: first-person-view, video-transmitters

This problem started a few days ago. After crashing with my quad I almost completely lose the video feed until I power cycle the drone. The only time I have video is when I get really close to the drone (Less than 1 meter), so it almost seems like the VTX enters pit mode when the crash happens.

I have pit mode on a switch, so I have tried turning it on and off again, but that does not help. It also seems like I can't enable pit mode at all (only disable. It is on when powering on), but that might not be relevant to this.

The VTX I'm using is the TBS UNIFY PRO 5G8 HV - RACE

Comment: Have you checked the antenna, cable and connector for damage? If the signal is not being radiated properly, this could explain the very short range.

Comment: It looked like they were connected properly, but I will check again

Comment: Did you manage to check the connection?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is undamaged and connected properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the antennae didn't feel loose, it probably was. After removing and screwing it back in I haven't had this problem again.